# Access dom element with vuejs and vuetify dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a div tag with an 'id="meet"' into v-dialog.

I need to access the node of this tag after I open the dialog. 
I am using

```
let node=document.querySelector("#meet").
```

My problem is that it always returns "null". 
Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/NWxKbXQ

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your CodePen, it returns null only on first open.

The content of the component is loaded dynamically by default, only after the first opening of the v-dialog.

You could add **eager** prop to v-dialog element to force it.

```
<v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
    max-width="290"
    eager
>
...
```